# Decode to a custom object from a JSON

Tags: json, swift, xcode, decode, swifty-json

I'm trying to decode from a JSON ( i use swiftyJSON and Alamofire for my HTTP requests). 
swiftyJsonVar is my JSON object

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()**

let user = try! decoder.decode([User.self], for:(swiftyJsonVar))**
```

When write this i have the following error

> incorrect argument label in call (have '*:for:', expected '*:from:'

So when I switch to " from: " i have the following error :

> Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'Data'* "

When i put the Data value that i get from my request before i convert it to a JSON it works fine but when the response is JSONArray i can't do this anymore. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: the decode function has the params `_ type: _.Type, from: Data`

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

The error "Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'Data'" clearly states what the problem is.

The data type for the "from" parameter needs to be Data, so you need to convert swiftyJsonVar. Something like `let data = try swiftyJsonVar.rawData()` if swiftJsonVar is a SwiftyJSON object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Please, please (learn to) read error messages. These are crystal clear.

The *left* side of the message is what you did wrong and the part after *expected* is what you got to do.

> "incorrect argument label in call (have '*:for:', expected '*:from:' "

What does it mean? You wrote `, for:` but the proper syntax is `, from:`. Probably there's even a <kbd>fix</kbd> button.

> " Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'Data' "

What does it mean? You passed a `JSON` type but the proper type is `Data`.

Forget SwiftyJSON and pass the raw data you received to the decoder and catch a possible error. Another mistake is the `Type` parameter. If **one** `User` is expected write `User.self`, if an **array** is expected write `[User].self`

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let user = try decoder.decode([User].self, from: data)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I didn't realize that swiftyJson was the problem and that it was that easy to parse an array of jsons ... Thanks again !